# Usage of the perfect gerund

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, subjects

Is there any grammatical error in this sentence:

> Having been up all night makes me tired

Can I use having been/done... as subject?

Comment: Which sentence? Are you talking about the title?

Comment: Look [here](http://josecarilloforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=1678.0)

Comment: Better asked on ELL.

Comment: If you post your question on [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (English language Learners) you will get the attention it deserves. There are native and non-native speakers who are passionate about English and will only be too happy to lend you a hand.

Answer (score 2):

*Having been up all night* is a perfectly good subject for a verb, and if that is all you are asking the question would fit better on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

What is not quite so certain, and what makes it interesting, is whether the verb should be *makes* rather than *made*.  If you are referring to last night, then *Having been up all night is making me tired* is an unexceptionable alternative to the usual *Staying up all night has made me tired*.  If you are referring to a few nights ago then ?*the reason I fell asleep yesterday was that having stayed up all night made/had made me tired* is grammatical though too convoluted for native speakers.If you mean as a general rule, the verb would certainly be *makes*, but I am uncertain whether you can make a habit of *having stayed up all night* rather than just *staying up*.My own rule in cases where I am uncertain is to avoid the construction is possible, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

In your case *having been up all night* is a subject. Despite it's somewhat wierd — thinking of *having been up all night makes me tired* as a fact (cause of present simple **makes**) — I think it is possible to consider your sentence grammatically correct.